# How could private modifier guard the encapsulation of an object, not class?

Tags: java, private, encapsulation

In Java, I understand why we define the instance field as private in some class, that is for protecting the encapsulation of a class. However, I am confused about the instance of that class. See below:

```
public class DotaHero {

private String name;

...

}
```

Till now, any outer class could not use the `name` directly! Then,

```
DotaHero zeus = new DotaHero();
zeus.name = "Zeus";
```

That is legal in Java. However, anyone who hate me would change my code easily, like:

```
zeus.name = "Chick";
```

Then, when I use object `zeus` to invoke the "zeusWrath" skill, it will show a script on screen, "The Chick is Furious!".........

Maybe someone would argue I was supposed to use setter method to define the name, and configure some checking mechanisms inside. However, my opponent still could directly access the `name` by `zeus` object.

I am sure I am misunderstanding something, but I can't find it...

Comment: You cannot do `zeus.name = "Chick";` because field `name` is private. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Try doing the `zeus.name = "Zeus"` assignment from another class, and see what happens.

Comment: OK, I found the problem. I put the main method in the class, so it could directly use the private fields. However, other class or object can't! Thanks a lot! How stupid I am :))))